# Synchronously work off all the pending tasks when using the in-memory broken in Celery

Tags: python, testing, celery

For testing purposes, I'm using the in-memory Celery broker: `"memory://localhost/"`. I can start a worker that will execute these tasks like this:

```
app = Celery('celery_app')
worker = app.Worker(app=app, pool='solo', concurrency=1)
thread = threading.Thread(target=worker.start)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
```

but how can I have more control over it? I want to execute all the tasks, blocking/synchronously, so that my tests can make strong assertions about the state of the system before and after running the tasks.

I am aware that if tasks generate more tasks, this could last forever, and that's OK.

Comment: Is this for testing / unit testing?  Or do you want to do this in production?  The reason that I ask is that celery offers eager execution using the `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` configuration.

Comment: @2ps: it is for testing (first three words of the question ;), but I don't want eager tasks, I want to be able to control when they are run.

Comment: But eager tasks do let you control when they are run, because they run exactly when called.